# How to predict next number from sequence of number with tf model.predict?

Tags: python, tensorflow, keras

Trying to make prediction of the next number but it didn't work well.
I have a list of 500 numbers :
[..., x, x, 3, 2, 1, 7, 2, 0, 3], i want to make prediction model with those 500 numbers to give me the possible 501 number.

I tried making model example with this code, it didn't go as expected with the example of 1 to 5 numbers.

```
xs = np.array([1, 2, 3, 4, 5])
ys = np.array([3, 7, 11, 15, 19])

model = tf.keras.Sequential([keras.layers.Dense(1, input_shape=(1,))])
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=200)
result = model.predict(xs)

print(result)
```

I use that code expecting prediction of the next number of xs.
it gave me this instead of 6 as the next number :

```
Epoch 200/200
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 6ms/step - loss: 161.2350 - mae: 11.2588
1/1 [==============================] - 0s 98ms/step
[[ 0.04653116]
 [-0.1042112 ]
 [-0.25495356]
 [-0.40569592]
 [-0.55643827]]
```

Comment: Does your list necessarily have equal difference? For eg:- a difference of 3 => [1, 4, 7, 10....]

Comment: @KillerRebooted No, its kinda "random" sequence. I want it to predict the next number based on those trained 500 numbers..

Comment: You need a classification model, not a regression one.

Comment: @Dr.Snoopy I thought I need regression model on this one, I'll check that out.

Comment: If you really want to solve this task, I would suggest using more complicate model (having more than one Dense layer).  Because what you're doing now is *input_value x weight + bias* and this is too easy solution for data that do not depend linearly on each (as in your example)

Comment: @Masha Can you give me reference of what should I search?

Answer (score 0):

To solve this kind of problem your model should be more complicated. Relationship between input value and target value are not linear (according to the example) so current model which looks like *input_value x weight + bias* barely can find a good solution.

I would suggest you to use something like this:

```
model = tf.keras.Sequential()
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16, input_shape=(1,)))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(16))
model.add(keras.layers.Dropout(0.1))
model.add(keras.layers.Dense(1))
model.compile(optimizer='adam', loss='mse', metrics=['mae'])
model.summary()

model.fit(xs, ys, epochs=200, verbose = 0)
result = model.predict(xs)

print(np.floor(result))
```

To improve results you can also play around with hyperparameters

Comment: Thanks for the answer, Its kinda work for at least it gave me the expected output number that make sense. But it doesn't really predict the next number ex : 1,2,3,4,5,? it should give me 6 as the next number or something close. And the second problem I got is when I work with more numbers, it printed the same lenght amount of number instead of giving me only 1 result of the possible next number. Like I just want it to only give me "6 " or just 1 number not more than 1.